# Azure Function App copy blob from one container to another using startCopy in java

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

I am using java to write a Azure Function App which is eventgrid trigger and the trigger is blobcreated. So when ever blob is created it will be trigerred and the function is to copy a blob from one container to another. I am using startCopy function from com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob. It was working fine but sometimes, It uses to copy files of zero bytes which are actually containing some data in source location. So at destination sometimes it dumps zero bytes of files. I would like to have a little help on this so that I could understand how to possibly handle this situation

```
CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = container.getBlockBlobReference(blobFileName);
CloudStorageAccount storageAccountdest = CloudStorageAccount.parse("something");
CloudBlobClient blobClientdest = storageAccountdest.createCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer destcontainer = blobClientdest.getContainerReference("something");
CloudBlockBlob destcloudBlockBlob = destcontainer.getBlockBlobReference();
destcloudBlockBlob.startCopy(cloudBlockBlob);
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying blobs across storage accounts is an async operation. When you call `startCopy` method, it just signals Azure Storage to copy a file. Actual file copy operation happens asynchronously and may take some time depending how how large file you're transferring.

I would suggest that you check the copy operation progress on the target blob to see how many bytes have been copied and if there's a failure in the copy operation. You can do so by fetching the properties of the target blob. A copy operation could potentially fail if the source blob is modified after the copy operation has started by Azure Storage.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem, and later figured out from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services)

> Event Grid isn't a data pipeline, and doesn't deliver the actual
>   object that was updated

Event grid will tell you that something has changed and that the actual message has a size limit and as long as the data that you are copying is within that limit it will be successful if not it will be 0 bytes. I was able to copy upto 1mb and beyond that it resulted 0 bytes. You can try and see if azure has increased by size limit in the recent.

However if you want to copy the complete data then you need to use Event Hub or Service Bus. For mine, I went with service bus.